# How can I force the footer to the bottom in this example?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I force #footer to the bottom of the page even when there's not enough page content to push it to the bottom?

https://www.bootply.com/qMgTsXOMJd

Please leave an example,
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Comment: This question has been asked, and answered, many times before, why is your instance different, why have all the other questions on this *exact* topic not solved your issue?

Comment: Also you don't show an example. At least provide code ***in your question*** if you want people to help with a specific example.

Comment: Im aware its been asked and answered many times before, the reason I ask is because it does not seem to be working with my code..

Comment: I dont know why its not working with my code, thats why I left a bootply link hoping someone could help me figure out whats going on

Comment: Those links look like a duplicate question but they show the old school way of doing it. This questions regards bootstrap which already has a solution for sticky footer which I linked to.

Comment: Hello, the css you provided did not seem to resolve the issue, been trying to fix this issue for hours but haven't figured it out :/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to do a sticky footer on the bootstrap doc website: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

In the example the footer is positioned absolute, this sticks it to the bottom of the screen and the body has a bottom margin that matches the height of the footer so content does not overflow the footer.

Add something like this to your css:

```
body {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

footer {
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I've tried sticking the footer with this example and couldn't seem to get it working, could you provide an example with the existing code please?

Comment: The answer is in the bootstrap link, inspect the footer and body elements and figure out how it works and how to apply it to your code.

Comment: don't copy it directly, so you don't have a footer element but an Id of footer so your css for footer would be `#footer {` instead

Comment: still not having any luck, i know this is a simple code except for some reason it isnt working with my code..

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a tag:  in the navigation and it'll force it to the bottom.

Comment: < div class= "keepOpen"></div >  this tag

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Thanks!